# Set html row colour depending on the value in the first column

Tags: python, html, css

I have a series of tables on a page and would like to set row colours depending on their position.

1 to 3 would be gold, silver and bronze.

4 - 10 would be green.

Then the rest just stay as bootstrap table-striped. I'm trying to work out how to do this with javascript but I don't really know my way around it.

Here's one of the tables (there are 9 of these on the page, all pretty similar):

```
<table class="table table-sm table-striped text-left">
    <thead class="text-white bg-info">
        <tr>
           <th scope="col">#</th>
           <th scope="col">Team</th>
           <th scope="col">Principal</th>
           <th scope="col">Last Race</th>
           <th scope="col">Points</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for row in tbls.league %}
        <tr>
            <td scope="row" class="counterCell"></td>
            <td>{{ row.TEAM_NAME }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.user }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.LAST_RACE }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.POINTS }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The position column is calcuated with a bit of css:

```
<style>
    table {
        counter-reset: tableCount;     
    }
    .counterCell:before {              
        content: counter(tableCount); 
        counter-increment: tableCount; 
    }
</style>
```

So basically I want to change the colour of a row depending on what is in that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest something like

```css
tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: gold;
}

 tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: silver;
}

 tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: bronze;
}
```

(use correct codes for your desired colors)

Comment: Yep that's perfect, cheers. I've edited it to work with bootstrap and to colour a row not just a column.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to anatolhiman. This is basically just his answer edited to fit my needs.

```
<style>
    tbody tr:nth-child(1) {
        background-color: gold !important;
      }
    tbody tr:nth-child(2) {
        background-color: silver !important;
    }

    tbody tr:nth-child(3) {
        background-color: bronze !important;
    }
</style>
```